# Angular nginx settings for Plesk

Tags: angular, nginx, plesk

I have an Angular 5 app which is setup on a domain using Plesk.

In order to work properly (to be able to refresh the app when is inside a route) I know I have to put some nginx directives under **Websites & Domains >> Apache & nginx Settings for [my.domain.name] >> Additional nginx directives**

Does anyone know them.

In theory something is needed to mask the URL (Angular is using routes on fake url which do not exist on the server and nginx is trying to solve them at refresh without success)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've added into **Websites & Domains >> Apache & nginx Settings for [my.domain.name] >> Additional nginx directives** to make it work as desired

```
location ~ ^/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no field "additional nginx directives". only "additional header". but that code does not work there

Comment: @daniel are you using nginx for that particular domain?

Comment: @daniel I've added ascreenshot for you, maybe your are looking in the wrong place. It's at the very bottom of the Apache & nginx Settings of your selected domain

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I dont't have this page section in my backend. Maybe because I don't have root rights